# disable/enable dropdown list options based on filtered D3.js data

Tags: d3.js

I have two dropdown lists that are dynamically populated from a database using PHP. They contain all values for a specified column e.g one contains all values for parameterType and the other all values for dateTimeTaken.

Is there any way to disable any of these options when the data is filtered and some of these options may no longer be applicable - basically I'm asking if dynamically populated dropdown lists can be updated when the data is, if so, how this can be accomplished?

**UPDATE:**

My data is in following format:

```
 [{"dateTimeTaken":"2013-01-01 14:05:14",
   "reading":"0.90000",
   "parameterType":"Flouride",
   "inspectionPoint_id":"2"}....
```

and I've attempted to do this using following code - but not doing anything??

```
 d3.json("HistoricData.php", function(error,data) 
 {
 var filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.inspectionPoint_id == i;})  
     filtered_data.forEach(function(d) {
     d.dateTimeTaken = parseDate(d.dateTimeTaken);
     d.reading = +d.reading;
     d.parameterType = d.parameterType;
     d.inspectionPoint_id = +d.inspectionPoint_id;      
 });

 var check = d3.select("selectparameter")//select dropdown list

 check.selectAll("option").each(checkOption);//select all options

 //for any of the options that don't match the parameterType's 
 //from the filtered dataset set display to none     
 var checkOption = function (d, e) {
 if(e !== d.values(d.parameterType)){
    return d3.select(this).attr("display", "none");
}
 };
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
 d3.select("#selectparameter")
    .append("select")
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(filtered_data)
    .enter().append("option")
    .text(function(d) { return d.parameterType; })
```

[image]

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097923/how-can-i-use-d3-or-just-javascript-to-set-a-form-option-as-being-selected

Comment: Thank you - that's shown me that it's possible but not sure how to implement this for what I need.  I have attempted it - see update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the usual data binding/update pattern (see e.g. [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html)) to update you options.

The first call (when you're binding the data) would look something like

```
check.selectAll("option").data(data)
     .enter().append("option")
     ...
```

To update, use something along the lines of

```
var newOptions = check.selectAll("option").data(filtered_data);
newOptions.enter().append("option")
          ...
newOptions.exit().attr("display", "none");
newOptions.attr("display", "block");
```

Note that by default d3 matches data by the index in the respective array, which is probably not what you want in this case. You can use the optional second argument to supply a function, e.g.

```
check.selectAll("option").data(filtered_data, function(d) { return d.inspectionPoint_id; });
```

Comment: Thank you - didn't quite work with my existing dropdown lists - so took an alternative route and appended the dropdown lists using D3 - see update 2 above.  They're being populated with the correct data but adding an option for each occurrence of relevant parameterType in array instead of one option for each distinct parameterType?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I think the best approach would be to first add options for all the data and then filter like I outlined in my answer.

Comment: See image above.  The filter operation filters the original data by inspection point - and the dropdown list then needs to depict each parameterType within that inspection point.  In this case it is Flouride so all correct apart from fact that one option is being added to dropdown for each occurence of Flouride within array rather than just displaying it once?  Your approach is perfect but how do I get the dropdown just to display Flouride, for example, once?

Comment: That depends on the data that you pass in. Simply pass in one element for each option, i.e. in your case one element for each parameterType.

Comment: Thank you - thats what I'm asking how to do? How would I do this - maybe specify a key?

Comment: Extract the values for parameterType and remove duplicates -- see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array